# Django with python3.4 and Graphite-web

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, graphite

I'm using the virtual environment Python3.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a Django webapp running without any issues. I want to be able to monitor the requests / traffic etc, however when I try to install the Graphite-Web (by running pip install graphite-web inside the venv) I'm getting the following:

```
Collecting graphite-web
  Using cached graphite-web-0.9.13.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-koiz44ft/graphite-web/setup.py", line 63, in <module>
        data_files=webapp_content.items() + storage_dirs + conf_files + examples,
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'list'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

      File "/tmp/pip-build-koiz44ft/graphite-web/setup.py", line 63, in <module>

        data_files=webapp_content.items() + storage_dirs + conf_files + examples,

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'list'

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-koiz44ft/graphite-web
```

It looks like this is due to the python version, because if I exit the venv (deactivate) and try to install using sudo apt-get install graphite-web, it installs however it shows up under python 2.7.

Now my question is, is there a way that I can get these things to work together (even though they require different versions of python)?

Comment: Use Python 2.7 for everything?

Comment: I have to use 3.4 for this unfortunately.

Comment: Then you have to either drop graphite-web as a dependency or go update it yourself to be Python3 compatible. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like graphite-web doesn't currently have Python 3 support (see the [check-dependencies](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/master/check-dependencies.py) script). You'll have to run it with Python 2.7.

Comment: Hello Alasdair and thanks for your reply. Can you point me in the right direction, because I don't know how can I run them together (as I've mentioned I have django running on venv which is 3.4).

Comment: You can create a new venv with Python 2.7 and install Django and graphite-web in that. Until you or somebody else adds Python 3 support to graphite-web, you don't have any other options.